# Convert from string to hex code (0x000000) in Three 3dObject in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to write a large number of objects at once and I want the color to fade. However, after making a string using `.toString(16)`, it doesn't read in the code where it says, `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '0x' + color, wireframe: false, opacity: 0.5 });`

Here's the code currently:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50);
                colorr = 254 / 10 * k;
                colorr = Math.round(colorr);
                colorr = colorr.toString(16);
                colorg = 254 / 10 * k;
                colorg = Math.round(colorg);
                colorg = colorg.toString(16);
                colorb = 254 / 10 * k;
                colorb = Math.round(colorb);
                colorb = colorb.toString(16);
                color = '0x' + colorr + colorg + colorb;
                material[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color, wireframe: false, opacity: 0.5 });


                mesh[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material[i]);
                mesh[i].position.x = -500 + (k * 100);
                mesh[i].position.y = -500 + (j * 100);
                mesh[i].position.z = -500 + (i * 100);
                scene.add(mesh[i]);
                objects.push(mesh[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

However, it just results in a grayish black color.

Comment: Did you look at the `color` string to see what you actually produced?

Comment: yeah, it was `0xe5e5e5` in the end. i even tried writing it in quotes `'0x0099ff'` and it turned out that didn't work. so, it has something to do with strings

Comment: If you want to use strings, you need to use '#', not '0x':  `material.color.setStyle( "#0099ff" );` three.js r.60

Comment: Are you sure? I think I tried that, but it didn't work. Or do you mean with both the '#' and the setStyle function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to make the components from `0` to `1` and use...

```
var color = new THREE.Color().setRGB(r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
> 0xe5e5e5
```

15066597

```
> parseInt('0xe5e5e5', 16)
```

15066597

Long story short, "0x" is just a convenient way to write numbers in hex so that they look like CSS colors, but JavaScript treats numbers written this way as normal (decimal) numbers, and so does Three.js. The `parseInt()` function will correctly convert a string from hex to decimal given the appropriate radix, so you can construct your color as a hex string and convert it to a number.